# Revit/AutoCAD Plugin connection to Webservice/Server possible?

Tags: web-services, autocad, revit, autocad-plugin

just a quick and basic principle question. Is it possible to create a Revit or AutoCAD plugin that can communicate with a Webservice/Server that is created by me (REST or Soap for example)?

For example the user uses my Plugin enters some numbers or other things. These numbers are send to my server, calculated and the result is send back to the plugin? Is that possible or blocked by Revit/AutoCAD.

Thanks for possible replies and have a nice day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course it is possible. Why on the hell would AutoCAD or Revit would block things like that?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Maybe security or money reasons  I thought.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, sure.

The Building Coder provides several examples.

Here is one:

https://github.com/jeremytammik/FireRatingCloud